# Fix regex expression to allow varations of user entered acronym

Tags: sql, regex, db2

Users can enter an acronym for "Post Office Box" a number of ways, like P.O. Box, PO Box, etc.

PO Boxes always have a number after it.

Am trying to get matches on all possible ways users could enter it in a string. Sometimes user will enter in something before PO Box, and I just need to match if it looks like the string is related to PO Box.

Looking for an expression that matches 1-6 below but doesn't match 7-10.

G.P.O. Box = General Post Office Box and that I'm trying to avoid matches on those.
I think the expression must allow either a blank or no other character before the 'P'.

I've come up with below, but it's not skipping GPO Boxes, or weird things like 'PPO BOX'

```
P{1}\s?\.?O{1}\.?\s+(BOX)\s+[0-9]*
```

[regex.com](https://regexr.com/4sri0)

1. PO BOX 123
2. P.O BOX 655
3. P.O. BOX 155
4. PO BOX 1
5. P O BOX 123
6. blahblah PO BOX 123
7. GPO BOX 123
8. blah G P O BOX 111
9. P O B OX
10. PP.O BOX 122

any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What type of SQL are you using? It makes a difference as to the regex constructs  you can use

Comment: using IBM DB2, but I thought I'd be able to use any valid expression... haven't used it a lot before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use negative lookbehind `(?<!G\.?)P` (P not preceded by `G\.?`):

```
WITH T (ID, STR) AS 
(
VALUES
  ( 1, 'PO BOX 123')
, ( 2, 'P.O BOX 655')
, ( 3, 'P.O. BOX 155')
, ( 4, 'PO BOX 1')
, ( 5, 'P O BOX 123')
, ( 6, 'blahblah PO BOX 123')
, ( 7, 'GPO BOX 123')
, ( 8, 'blah G P O BOX 111')
, ( 9, 'P O B OX')
, (10, 'PP.O BOX 122')

, (11, 'G.P.O BOX 122')
)
SELECT T.*
, REGEXP_LIKE(STR, '(?<!G\.?)P\s?\.?O\.?\s+BOX\s+[0-9]*') FLAG
FROM T

|ID         |STR                |FLAG |
|-----------|-------------------|-----|
|1          |PO BOX 123         |true |
|2          |P.O BOX 655        |true |
|3          |P.O. BOX 155       |true |
|4          |PO BOX 1           |true |
|5          |P O BOX 123        |true |
|6          |blahblah PO BOX 123|true |
|7          |GPO BOX 123        |false|
|8          |blah G P O BOX 111 |true |
|9          |P O B OX           |false|
|10         |PP.O BOX 122       |true |
|11         |G.P.O BOX 122      |false|
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and explanation. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
'^\s*P[. ]*O[. ]*Box\s*[0-6]$'
```

Comment: That nearly does it, but doesn't cover scenario 6 where user has entered in a string prior to PO Box. I need it to return "found" if it's anywhere in the string and can't be a GPO box. Thanks